# PowerShell Array list assignment and Where-Object fails when Where-Object returns one item. Works with 2+ items

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Long time searcher, first time poster. :-)

When piping an array list to Where-Object and assigning it back to another array list, a conversion error is generated when the result of the Where-Object is a single item. But the same command succeeds when two or more items are returned. Is this a PowerShell bug or am I missing something?

Why does this fail?

```
PS C:\> [System.Collections.ArrayList]$AL1 = @(1,2,3)
PS C:\> [System.Collections.ArrayList]$AL2 = $AL1 | Where-Object {$_ -ge 3}
Cannot convert the "3" value of type "System.Int32" to type "System.Collections.ArrayList".
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.Collections.ArrayList]$AL2 = $AL1 | Where-Object {$_ -ge 3}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

But if the result of the Where-Object is two or more items it does not fail.

```
PS C:\> [System.Collections.ArrayList]$AL1 = @(1,2,3)
PS C:\> [System.Collections.ArrayList]$AL2 = $AL1 | Where-Object {$_ -ge 2}
PS C:\> $AL2
2
3
PS C:\>
```

Also the assignment succeeds if you first create the second array list via New-Object.

```
PS C:\> $AL3 = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
PS C:\> $AL3 = $AL1 | Where-Object {$_ -ge 3}
PS C:\> $AL3
3
```

Tested on PSVersion 5.1.19041.1682 and core 7.0.7

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is expected, PowerShell enumerates all output and, since one item results from the expression:

```
$AL1 | Where-Object { $_ -ge 3 }
```

Its trying to coerce an `int` to the type `System.Collections.ArrayList`, however only types implementing [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-7.0) can be coerced to it, hence the error:

```bash
PS \> [System.Collections.ArrayList] 3
```

> InvalidArgument: Cannot convert the "3" value of type "System.Int32" to type "System.Collections.ArrayList".

You have three easy workarounds:

1. Don't constrain your variable to be of the type `System.Collections.ArrayList`, let PowerShell dynamically assign the resulting type.
2. Wrap your expression with the [Array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--), so, no matter how many elements results from the expression, the type **will always be an `IEnumerable`**:

```bash
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $AL1 = @(1, 2, 3)
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $AL2 = @($AL1 | Where-Object { $_ -ge 3 })
```

3. Use the [`.Where` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#where) instead which always returns [`` Collection`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1?view=net-7.0) (an `IEnumerable`):

```bash
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $AL1 = @(1, 2, 3)
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $AL2 = $AL1.Where{ $_ -ge 3 }
```

---

Other workarounds are possible either using [`Write-Output -NoEnumerate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.3#-noenumerate) or [Comma operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-):

```bash
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $AL1 = @(1, 2, 3)
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $AL2 = Write-Output ($AL1 | Where-Object { $_ -ge 3 }) -NoEnumerate
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $AL2 = , ($AL1 | Where-Object { $_ -ge 3 })
```

---

As for:

> Also the assignment succeeds if you first create the second array list via `New-Object`.

Correct, you're not constraining the variable in this case:

```
$AL3 = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$AL3 = $AL1 | Where-Object { $_ -ge 3 }
$AL3.GetType() # => Int32, no longer an ArrayList
```

---

For more info, see relevant documentation: **[about Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.3)**.